# Array parsing and converting to new array List

Tags: arrays

How to convert below array to specific output?
Input:

```
[
  {
    "id": "9664581",
    "isSelected": true,
    "isExpanded": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "cells": [
      {
        "id": "9664581:att_name",
        "value": "Test1 att_name",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "att_name"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9664581:att_email",
        "value": "test1@gmail.com",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "att_email"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9664581:comp_name",
        "value": "Test1 comp_name",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "comp_name"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9664581:attendee_ctry",
        "value": "Test cnt",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "attendee_ctry"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9664581:sources",
        "value": "Test DB",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "sources"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "9528552",
    "isSelected": true,
    "isExpanded": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "cells": [
      {
        "id": "9528552:att_name",
        "value": "Test2 att_name",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "att_name"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9528552:att_email",
        "value": "Test2@gmail.com",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "att_email"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9528552:comp_name",
        "value": "Dsd comp_name",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "comp_name"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9528552:attendee_ctry",
        "value": "Test2 cnt",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "attendee_ctry"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "9528552:sources",
        "value": "Test2 DB",
        "isEditable": false,
        "isEditing": false,
        "isValid": true,
        "errors": null,
        "info": {
          "header": "sources"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

output should be like 
**output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "9664581",
        "name": "Test1 att_name",
        "email": test1@gmail.com
    },
    {
        "id": "9528552",
        "name": "Test2 att_name",
        "email": test2@gmail.com
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you done so far ? Show us the code you've done so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand your data.

It appears that the `id` comes right off of each object. As for the `name` and `email`, those are the values of the first and second cell. This turns into a trivial mapping.

You could also try to look-up the cells by their header:

```js
function transformData(data) {
  return data.map(item => {
    return {
      id : item.id,
      name : item.cells.find(cell => cell.info.header.endsWith('name')).value,
      email : item.cells.find(cell => cell.info.header.endsWith('email')).value
    };
  });
}
```

```js
console.log(transformData(getData()));

function transformData(data) {
  return data.map(item => {
    return {
      id : item.id,
      name : item.cells[0].value,
      email : item.cells[1].value
    };
  });
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "id": "9664581",
    "isSelected": true,
    "isExpanded": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "cells": [{
      "id": "9664581:att_name",
      "value": "Test1 att_name",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "att_name"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9664581:att_email",
      "value": "test1@gmail.com",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "att_email"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9664581:comp_name",
      "value": "Test1 comp_name",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "comp_name"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9664581:attendee_ctry",
      "value": "Test cnt",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "attendee_ctry"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9664581:sources",
      "value": "Test DB",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "sources"
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "9528552",
    "isSelected": true,
    "isExpanded": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "cells": [{
      "id": "9528552:att_name",
      "value": "Test2 att_name",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "att_name"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9528552:att_email",
      "value": "Test2@gmail.com",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "att_email"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9528552:comp_name",
      "value": "Dsd comp_name",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "comp_name"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9528552:attendee_ctry",
      "value": "Test2 cnt",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "attendee_ctry"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "9528552:sources",
      "value": "Test2 DB",
      "isEditable": false,
      "isEditing": false,
      "isValid": true,
      "errors": null,
      "info": {
        "header": "sources"
      }
    }]
  }];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Polywhirl, it's nice solution, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
let output = input.map(v => {
    let name = '';
    let email = '';

    v.cells.map(obj => {
      if(obj.info.header === 'att_name') {
        name = obj.value
      }

      if(obj.info.header === 'att_email') {
        email = obj.value
      }
      return
    })

    return  {
      "id": v.id,
      "name": name,
      "email": email
    }
  })
```